# как найти количество элементов массива, значение и индекс которых больше 10

Tags: javascript

```js
let x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20];

for(let i = 0;i<x.length;i++){
    if(x>10 && x[i]>10){
       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Только не забывайте, что индекс начинается всегда с `0`. 
Значение `1` - будет иметь индекс `0`, `2` будет иметь индекс `1` и так далее.

```js
    let x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20];
    var count = 0;
    for(let i = 0;i<x.length;i++) {
        if (i > 10 && x[i] > 10) { // i - это ключ, x[i]- цифра
            count += 1;
        }
    }
    console.log(count);
```

Если хотите, чтобы значение и индекс совпадали, то возьмите отсчёт `count` с единицы
Пример:

```js
    let x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20];
    var count = 1;
    for(let i = 0;i<x.length;i++) {
        if (i > 10 && x[i] > 10) { // i - это ключ, x[i]- цифра
            count += 1;
        }
    }
    console.log(count);
```

Так же можно добавить в массив любое значение в позицию индекса `0` или в `if (i > 10 && x[i] > 10) {` начинать отчёт от 9 `if (i > 9 && x[i] > 10) {`

Answer (score 1):

Чтоб получить все элементы массива, индекс которых больше за 10, итерацию следует начинать с значения больше за 10 и тогда придется делать только 1 проверку: больше ли значение по индексу за 10.

```js
let x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20];
let count = 0;
for(let i = 11;i<x.length;i++) {
  if (x[i] > 10) {
    count += 1;
  }
}
console.log(count);
```